# Build failed Issue in signtool.exe exited with code 123

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, signtool

I have opened my Visual Studio 2013 project in Visual Studio 2015. When I am trying to build am getting below issue:

> The command “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe” sign /v /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f "asdf2017.pfx" /p asdf985 "asdf_PC_Link.exe" exited with code 123

But it is working well in Visual Studio 2013.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you using a code signing certificate and is it expired?

Comment: Ya using but certificate is not expired . It is working with V.S 2013

Comment: Is this path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe" accessible via the cli?

Comment: Yes that is the Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin ...How can i access this VIA Commad Line Interface @ThatAwesomeCoder

Comment: With Cmd.exe i went to the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin .. It is accessible

Comment: Have you tried running VS 2015 as administrator?

Comment: Yes My VS2015 opened with Administrator

Comment: Just want to double check the "signtool.exe" was located in the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\"?

Comment: Yes am sure Signtool.exe is available at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin